# Android deal with lot of intents

Tags: android, android-intent

My app is design to get messages from an embedded Bluetooth device. While I was working with sensors which sends data each second or more, it was not such a big deal to broadcast intents to activities. The only visible slow down was when the Bluetooth device flushed its buffer.
Now I need to deal with high refresh rate sensors (such as ECG, every 2ms) so I have to be little more cleaver because the number of intents makes visualization not in real time (there is more measures incoming than displayed).

I try to work with `putIntegerArrayListExtra()` to send data each 2 seconds but now I get a **A.N.R**.

Is someone can advise me to deal with lot of intents? (It seems my service memory also grow up to much).

To bypass intents, I have to send an object from a service to an activity. As far I now this is impossible and the reason of `Intent`.

EDIT:

I had underestimate binding. In fact it enables activities to get from the service an instance of a "`DeviceDriver`" which register listeners to perform callback. As I can retrieve the instance of the driver in the activity, I can register it as a listener and cut down all intents between service and activities (At least for data exchange).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use binding to pass data from service to intent:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: Obviously I underestimate binding, I didn't know that enable to pass instance to activities. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I advice you to not use intents. Try to use thread inside activity or shared memory and synchronization.